# How can I read a file as nested lists of coordinates for multiple polygons?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file-io, matplotlib

I have a file with many sections like the following:

```
[40.742742,-73.993847]
[40.739389,-73.985667]
[40.74715499999999,-73.97992]
[40.750573,-73.988415]
[40.742742,-73.993847]

[40.734706,-73.991915]
[40.736917,-73.990263]
[40.736104,-73.98846]
[40.740315,-73.985263]
[40.74364800000001,-73.993353]
[40.73729099999999,-73.997988]
[40.734706,-73.991915]

[40.729226,-74.003463]
[40.7214529,-74.006038]
[40.717745,-74.000389]
[40.722299,-73.996634]
[40.725291,-73.994413]
[40.729226,-74.003463]
[40.754604,-74.007836]
[40.751289,-74.000649]
[40.7547179,-73.9983309]
[40.75779,-74.0054339]
[40.754604,-74.007836]
```

I need to read in each of these sections as a list of pairs of coordinates (Each section being separated by an extra `\n`).

In a similar file I have (same except there are no extra newline breaks), I am drawing one polygon from the whole file. I can use the following code to read in the coordinates and draw it in matplotlib:

```
mVerts = []
with open('Manhattan_Coords.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pair = [float(s) for s in line.strip()[1:-1].split(", ")]
        mVerts.append(pair)

plt.plot(*zip(*mVerts))
plt.show()
```

How can I accomplish the same task, except with many more than 1 polygon, each polygon in my file separated by an extra newline?

Comment: Why is the newline relavent? The form is `[#,#]`. Do you mean there could be `[#,#][#,#][#,#]\n` that relates these 3 coordinates separate from the others ?

Comment: [#,#]\n[#,#]\n  . . .  \n[#,#]\n\n is one polygon, with any given number of coordinates before that newline

Comment: Well you can parse each line as a string, then put up a regex to find each pair. Is it the regex you have trouble with, say to strip off the decoration `[,]` ?

Comment: I can use regex to find each pair and put all those pairs into a list, but I need a way of creating sublists with those pairs, each sublist of coordinates being cut off when an extra newline is found, starting the next sublist of coordinates.

Comment: Where did this input come from? It looks an awful lot like someone either wrote the `repr` of each Python list to a file, or stored it as JSON. If that's true, why not just parse it appropriately, with `ast.literal_eval` or `json.load`?

Comment: Here's how a sample of the original formatting: 40.742742,-73.993847|40.739389,-73.985667|40.74715499999999,-73.97992|40.750573,-73.988415|40.742742,-73.993847+40.734706,-73.991915|40.736917,-73.990263|40.736104,-73.98846|40.740315,-73.985263|40.74364800000001,-73.993353|40.73729099999999,-73.997988|40.734706,-73.991915+40.729226,-74.003463|40.7214529,-74.006038|40.717745,-74.000389|40.722299,-73.996634|40.725291,-73.994413|40.729226,-74.003463

Answer (score 4):

Here's my personal favorite way to "chunk" a file into groups of things that are separated by whitespace:

```
from itertools import groupby

def chunk_groups(it):
     stripped_lines = (x.strip() for x in it)
     for k, group in groupby(stripped_lines, bool):
         if k:
             yield list(group)
```

And I'd recommend `ast.literal_eval` to turn those string-representations of lists into actual python lists:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open(filename) as f:
     result = [[literal_eval(li) for li in chunk] for chunk in chunk_groups(f)]
```

Gives:

```
result
Out[66]: 
[[[40.742742, -73.993847],
  [40.739389, -73.985667],
  [40.74715499999999, -73.97992],
  [40.750573, -73.988415],
  [40.742742, -73.993847]],
 [[40.734706, -73.991915],
  [40.736917, -73.990263],
  [40.736104, -73.98846],
  [40.740315, -73.985263],
  [40.74364800000001, -73.993353],
  [40.73729099999999, -73.997988],
  [40.734706, -73.991915]],
 [[40.729226, -74.003463],
  [40.7214529, -74.006038],
  [40.717745, -74.000389],
  [40.722299, -73.996634],
  [40.725291, -73.994413],
  [40.729226, -74.003463],
  [40.754604, -74.007836],
  [40.751289, -74.000649],
  [40.7547179, -73.9983309],
  [40.75779, -74.0054339],
  [40.754604, -74.007836]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on roippi's idea, using `json` instead of `ast`,

```
import json
from itertools import groupby

with open(FILE, "r") as coodinates_file:
    grouped = groupby(coodinates_file, lambda line: line.isspace())
    groups = (group for empty, group in grouped if not empty)

    polygons = [[json.loads(line) for line in group] for group in groups]
```

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(polygons)
#>>> [[[40.742742, -73.993847],
#>>>   [40.739389, -73.985667],
#>>>   [40.74715499999999, -73.97992],
#>>>   [40.750573, -73.988415],
#>>>   [40.742742, -73.993847]],
#>>>  [[40.734706, -73.991915],
#>>>   [40.736917, -73.990263],
#>>>   [40.736104, -73.98846],
#>>>   [40.740315, -73.985263],
#>>>   [40.74364800000001, -73.993353],
#>>>   [40.73729099999999, -73.997988],
#>>>   [40.734706, -73.991915]],
#>>>  [[40.729226, -74.003463],
#>>>   [40.7214529, -74.006038],
#>>>   [40.717745, -74.000389],
#>>>   [40.722299, -73.996634],
#>>>   [40.725291, -73.994413],
#>>>   [40.729226, -74.003463],
#>>>   [40.754604, -74.007836],
#>>>   [40.751289, -74.000649],
#>>>   [40.7547179, -73.9983309],
#>>>   [40.75779, -74.0054339],
#>>>   [40.754604, -74.007836]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of nifty approaches taken in the answers already posted. There's nothing wrong with any of them.

However, there's also nothing wrong with taking the obvious-but-readable approach.

On a side note, you seem to be working with geographic data.  This sort of format is something you'll run into all of the time, and the segment delimiter often isn't something as obvious as an extra newline.  (There are a lot of fairly bad ad-hoc "ascii export" formats out there, particularly in obscure proprietary software. For example, one common format uses an `F` at the end of the last line in a segment as the delimiter (i.e. `1.0  2.0F`). Plenty of others don't use a delimiter at all, and require you to start a new segment/polygon if you're more than "x" distance away from the last point.)  Furthermore, these things often wind up being multi-GB ascii files, so reading the entire thing into memory can be impractical.

---

My point is: Regardless of the approach you choose, make sure you understand it.  You're going to be doing this again, and it's going to be just different enough to be difficult to generalize. You absolutely *should* learn libraries like `itertools` well, but make sure you fully understand the functions you're calling.

---

Here's one version of the "obvious-but-readable" approach. It's more verbose, but no one is going to be left scratching their heads as to what it does.  (You could write this same logic several slightly different ways. Use what makes the most sense to you.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def polygons(infile):
    group = []
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            coords = line[1:-1].split(',')
            group.append(map(float, coords))
        else:
            yield group
            group = []
    else:
        yield group

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

with open('data.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for poly in polygons(infile):
        ax.plot(*zip(*poly))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, but I get an error when I try to run it: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tri_State_Maps.py", line 42, in <module>
    ax.plot(*zip(*poly))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'